# Faraday::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram, instagram-api

Getting `Farday::SSLError` while fetching posts from instagram.

I have refred this [tutorial](https://blog.ajmalafif.com/instagram-gem-with-rails/)

Below is the code snippet

Gemfile

```
 gem 'instagram'
```

config\initializers\instagram.rb

```
require "sinatra"
require "instagram"

Instagram.configure do |config|
  config.client_id = "4ad05f8aa5a24827b6c5e3c825ff2528"
  config.access_token = "06a7eb3dd2ec45d6a576e3b3576fc423"
end
```

homecontroller

```
def index
  @galleries = Gallery.all
  @banners = Slideshow.where(gallery_id: nil)
  @instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media("592393738", {:count => 1})
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @instagram.each do |instagram| %>
   <%= image_tag instagram.images.standard_resolution.url %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the view, replace `instagram.images.standard_resolution.url` with `instagram.images.standard_resolution.url.sub(/^https?\:/, '')`

Alternatively, you can try this gem  `https://github.com/agilie/instagram_api_gem`

Comment: i get the same error SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed, even after the change u suggested.

Comment: I had faced a similar issue with that gem and I was suggested to change to this. Here is a link to a sample application using the suggested gem  https://github.com/Kedarnag13/SampleInstagram

Comment: oh okay fine.. il look into the smapleapp u have sent .. thanks

Comment: i looked into ua sample app and tried implementing that to my project, but  stil i get the same error

Comment: Can you try this `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<user-id>/media/recent/`. It's a GET request

Comment: should i place the user id number and check the url

Comment: Yes, replace `<user-id>` in the URL and ping that. I believe there is an new way of getting information as well. You can try this too `https://instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17888483320059182&variables={"id":"user_id","first":20,"after":null}`

Comment: but when i do that i get error. error_message: "Missing client_id or access_token URL parameter."
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177547/discussion-between-kedarnag-mukanahallipatna-and-sushma-kv).